# Missing version when using bom

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I'm trying to create a multi module Maven Spring project:

```
Parent
|-Bom
|-Customers
  |- Customers-main
  |- Customers-client
|- other modules...
```

The idea is all projects import the bom so I can keep version consistent across modules.

When trying to build the Customers module, I get these errors:

```
[ERROR]   The project com.imgarena:customers:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\dev\IMGArena\customers\pom.xml) has 2 errors
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar is missing. @ line 52, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar is missing. @ line 56, column 21
```

Inside IntelliJ, the versions are resolved correctly (it even shows the gutter icon that jumps to the bom when clicked):
[image: Versions are resolved OK in IntelliJ]

But when running with Maven 3.6.3 CLI, I got the error.

Parent pom.xml: (most dependencies are removed for brevity)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.imgarena</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <!-- chaged fom jar to pom -->
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>customers</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <springfox-version>3.0.0</springfox-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Bom pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.imgarena</groupId>
    <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.imgarena</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

customers pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.imgarena</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>customers</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>customers-client</module>
        <module>customers-main</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.imgarena</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</project>
```

Comment: The version for springfox is not available in your bom module ... that's the reason...

Comment: Thanks but no, that's not the reason, because the version is defined in the parent pom which the bom inherits from, and it should be replaced (as it happens in IntelliJ). Anyway, I'll modify it in the question so it's not confusing.

Comment: Please make an example project on. Github or alike....

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the reason was I was missing including the bom as a module in the parent pom:

```
    <modules>
        <module>customers</module>
        <module>bom</module>
    </modules>
```

Don't know exactly why, but once I added this everything worked.